# Possibility to configure Akka to use blocking or non blocking i/o?

Tags: scala, blocking, akka, actor, nonblocking

Is it possible to configure Akka to use blocking or non blocking i/o?

Thanks.

Comment: @Roland Kuhn Network i/o as in this: http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3837316/Non-Blocking-IO-Made-Possible-in-Java.htm

Answer (score 0):

Akka is an actor system for concurrency and parallel execution. As such, you pass event-based messages into actors to make them do things. When you send a message, it goes into the actor's input queue, leaving the sender to go and do something else. But the sender can hold a future instead and later block when it wants to collect a result.

The actor itself may possibly use blocking i/o, but this doesn't block the actor's clients.

Answer (score 0):

Akka IO is non-blocking, please refer to the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/io.html